# why I can't use scrapy with the proxy of https

Tags: scrapy

I write a simple test to validate the https proxy in scrapy.but it didn't work

```
 class BaiduSpider(scrapy.Spider):
         name = 'baidu'
         allowed_domains = ['baidu.com']
         start_urls = ['http://www.baidu.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status == 200:
            print(response.text)
```

and the file of middlewares like this:
class DynamicProxyDownloaderMiddleware(object):

```
 def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'https://183.159.88.182:8010'
```

also the file of settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = { 
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
   'requestTest.middlewares.DynamicProxyDownloaderMiddleware': 100
}
```

when using the lib of requests.the https proxy works.but changed to scrapy.it confused me.So anybody know this?

the log file:

```
[the log file][1]
```

[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying http://www.baidu.com/> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: 
the proxy address is https://183.159.88.182:8010

Comment: Show your scrapy version and scraping log.

Comment: scrapy version 1.5.0